# Как прописать путь до библиотеки в cmake?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, makefile, grpc

Ubuntu 18.04

Пытаюсь собрать helloworld для grpc, сам grpc и protobuf установил не в стандартную либу, соответственно при сборке выдает ошибку

```
    DEPENDENCY ERROR

You don't have the grpc c++ protobuf plugin installed in your path.
Please install grpc. You can find it here:

   https://github.com/grpc/grpc

Here is what I get when trying to detect if you have the plugin:

which grpc_cpp_plugin
Makefile:105: recipe for target 'system-check' failed
make: [system-check] Error 1 (игнорирование)


Makefile:105: recipe for target 'system-check' failed
make: *** [system-check] Error 1
```

Как мне указать путь до либы с grpc? И надо делать это в самом makefile или в  cmakelist?

**MakeFile**

```
HOST_SYSTEM = $(shell uname | cut -f 1 -d_)
SYSTEM ?= $(HOST_SYSTEM)
CXX = g++
CPPFLAGS += `pkg-config --cflags protobuf grpc`
CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
ifeq ($(SYSTEM),Darwin)
LDFLAGS += -L/usr/local/lib `pkg-config --libs protobuf grpc++ grpc`\
           -lgrpc++_reflection\
           -ldl
else
LDFLAGS += -L/usr/local/lib `pkg-config --libs protobuf grpc++ grpc`\
           -Wl,--no-as-needed -lgrpc++_reflection -Wl,--as-needed\
           -ldl
endif
PROTOC = protoc
GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN = grpc_cpp_plugin
GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_PATH ?= `which $(GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN)`

PROTOS_PATH = ../../protos

vpath %.proto $(PROTOS_PATH)

all: system-check greeter_client greeter_server greeter_async_client greeter_async_client2 greeter_async_server

greeter_client: helloworld.pb.o helloworld.grpc.pb.o greeter_client.o
    $(CXX) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

greeter_server: helloworld.pb.o helloworld.grpc.pb.o greeter_server.o
    $(CXX) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

greeter_async_client: helloworld.pb.o helloworld.grpc.pb.o greeter_async_client.o
    $(CXX) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

greeter_async_client2: helloworld.pb.o helloworld.grpc.pb.o greeter_async_client2.o
    $(CXX) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

greeter_async_server: helloworld.pb.o helloworld.grpc.pb.o greeter_async_server.o
    $(CXX) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

.PRECIOUS: %.grpc.pb.cc
%.grpc.pb.cc: %.proto
    $(PROTOC) -I $(PROTOS_PATH) --grpc_out=. --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=$(GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_PATH) $<

.PRECIOUS: %.pb.cc
%.pb.cc: %.proto
    $(PROTOC) -I $(PROTOS_PATH) --cpp_out=. $<

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.pb.cc *.pb.h greeter_client greeter_server greeter_async_client greeter_async_client2 greeter_async_server


# The following is to test your system and ensure a smoother experience.
# They are by no means necessary to actually compile a grpc-enabled software.

PROTOC_CMD = which $(PROTOC)
PROTOC_CHECK_CMD = $(PROTOC) --version | grep -q libprotoc.3
PLUGIN_CHECK_CMD = which $(GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN)
HAS_PROTOC = $(shell $(PROTOC_CMD) > /dev/null && echo true || echo false)
ifeq ($(HAS_PROTOC),true)
HAS_VALID_PROTOC = $(shell $(PROTOC_CHECK_CMD) 2> /dev/null && echo true || echo false)
endif
HAS_PLUGIN = $(shell $(PLUGIN_CHECK_CMD) > /dev/null && echo true || echo false)

SYSTEM_OK = false
ifeq ($(HAS_VALID_PROTOC),true)
ifeq ($(HAS_PLUGIN),true)
SYSTEM_OK = true
endif
endif

system-check:
ifneq ($(HAS_VALID_PROTOC),true)
    @echo " DEPENDENCY ERROR"
    @echo
    @echo "You don't have protoc 3.0.0 installed in your path."
    @echo "Please install Google protocol buffers 3.0.0 and its compiler."
    @echo "You can find it here:"
    @echo
    @echo "   https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.0.0"
    @echo
    @echo "Here is what I get when trying to evaluate your version of protoc:"
    @echo
    -$(PROTOC) --version
    @echo
    @echo
endif
ifneq ($(HAS_PLUGIN),true)
    @echo " DEPENDENCY ERROR"
    @echo
    @echo "You don't have the grpc c++ protobuf plugin installed in your path."
    @echo "Please install grpc. You can find it here:"
    @echo
    @echo "   https://github.com/grpc/grpc"
    @echo
    @echo "Here is what I get when trying to detect if you have the plugin:"
    @echo
    -which $(GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN)
    @echo
    @echo
endif
ifneq ($(SYSTEM_OK),true)
    @false
endif
```

**CMakeLists**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)



project(HelloWorld C CXX)



if(NOT MSVC)

  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

else()

  add_definitions(-D_WIN32_WINNT=0x600)

endif()



if(GRPC_AS_SUBMODULE)

  # One way to build a projects that uses gRPC is to just include the

  # entire gRPC project tree via "add_subdirectory".

  # This approach is very simple to use, but the are some potential

  # disadvantages:

  # * it includes gRPC's CMakeLists.txt directly into your build script

  #   without and that can make gRPC's internal setting interfere with your

  #   own build.

  # * depending on what's installed on your system, the contents of submodules

  #   in gRPC's third_party/* might need to be available (and there might be

  #   additional prerequisites required to build them). Consider using

  #   the gRPC_*_PROVIDER options to fine-tune the expected behavior.

  #

  # A more robust approach to add dependency on gRPC is using

  # cmake's ExternalProject_Add (see cmake_externalproject/CMakeLists.txt).



  # Include the gRPC's cmake build (normally grpc source code would live

  # in a git submodule called "third_party/grpc", but this example lives in

  # the same repository as gRPC sources, so we just look a few directories up)

  add_subdirectory(../../.. ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/grpc EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)

  message(STATUS "Using gRPC via add_subdirectory.")



  # After using add_subdirectory, we can now use the grpc targets directly from

  # this build.

  set(_PROTOBUF_LIBPROTOBUF libprotobuf)

  set(_PROTOBUF_PROTOC $<TARGET_FILE:protoc>)

  set(_GRPC_GRPCPP_UNSECURE grpc++_unsecure)

  set(_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE $<TARGET_FILE:grpc_cpp_plugin>)

else()

  # This branch assumes that gRPC and all its dependencies are already installed

  # on this system, so they can be located by find_package().



  # Find Protobuf installation

  # Looks for protobuf-config.cmake file installed by Protobuf's cmake installation.

  set(protobuf_MODULE_COMPATIBLE TRUE)

  find_package(Protobuf CONFIG REQUIRED)

  message(STATUS "Using protobuf ${protobuf_VERSION}")



  set(_PROTOBUF_LIBPROTOBUF protobuf::libprotobuf)

  set(_PROTOBUF_PROTOC $<TARGET_FILE:protobuf::protoc>)



  # Find gRPC installation

  # Looks for gRPCConfig.cmake file installed by gRPC's cmake installation.

  find_package(gRPC CONFIG REQUIRED)

  message(STATUS "Using gRPC ${gRPC_VERSION}")



  set(_GRPC_GRPCPP_UNSECURE gRPC::grpc++_unsecure)

  set(_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE $<TARGET_FILE:gRPC::grpc_cpp_plugin>)

endif()



# Proto file

get_filename_component(hw_proto "../../protos/helloworld.proto" ABSOLUTE)

get_filename_component(hw_proto_path "${hw_proto}" PATH)



# Generated sources

set(hw_proto_srcs "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/helloworld.pb.cc")

set(hw_proto_hdrs "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/helloworld.pb.h")

set(hw_grpc_srcs "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/helloworld.grpc.pb.cc")

set(hw_grpc_hdrs "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/helloworld.grpc.pb.h")

add_custom_command(

      OUTPUT "${hw_proto_srcs}" "${hw_proto_hdrs}" "${hw_grpc_srcs}" "${hw_grpc_hdrs}"

      COMMAND ${_PROTOBUF_PROTOC}

      ARGS --grpc_out "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"

        --cpp_out "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"

        -I "${hw_proto_path}"

        --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc="${_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE}"

        "${hw_proto}"

      DEPENDS "${hw_proto}")



# Include generated *.pb.h files

include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")



#Моя попытка решить проблему.

#INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/home/user/local_SDK/include)

#LINK_DIRECTORIES(/home/user/local_SDK/lib)

#add_executable(helloworld src/helloworld.cpp)

#TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(heloworld *.so)



# Targets greeter_[async_](client|server)

foreach(_target

  greeter_client greeter_server

  greeter_async_client greeter_async_server)

  add_executable(${_target} "${_target}.cc"

    ${hw_proto_srcs}

    ${hw_grpc_srcs})

  target_link_libraries(${_target}

    ${_GRPC_GRPCPP_UNSECURE}

    ${_PROTOBUF_LIBPROTOBUF})

endforeach()
```

Comment: Что я не понял: вы используете cmake вместе с Makefile?

Comment: Это взятый пример с репа grpc, и насколько я понимаю его можно собрать make или cmake, я честно говоря не сильно шарю в них, просто выложил оба файла, так как решение какое будет мне не принципиально, мне главное собрать пример и посмотреть его.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запустите:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH=path/to/gprc ..
```